# Ubuntu 16.10 - Virtualbox - Hostname resolves with host command but not with ping or in browser

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns, 16.10

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 on Virtualbox with a Windows 10 host. Networking is using bridged mode and everything seems to work well except we have a hostname setup for one the network services we use.  For some reason this hostname wont resolve when I try to ping it or when I try to use it in the browser.

Strangely though it does resolve to the correct IP when I use `nslookup` or `host`.  Connection manager is using the correct up for our DNS server.

One interesting this is that this hostname does have a `-` in the middle and a `.local` at the end of the hostname.

Any idea on what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hostnames that end in .local are treated as mDNS in Linux by default, and won't perform a normal DNS lookup (read more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local). You can change this behavior by editing /etc/nsswitch.conf and look for the line

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

and change the order so DNS takes precedence, like:

```
hosts: files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
```